# cordova pugins js file configuration

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, websocket

I'm writing an hybrid app for android with cordova, but i find a strange behavior.
When i build tha app from the command line with cordova build,the application cleans the assets folder as expect, but it creates the apk with a different cordova_plugin.js files from the one in the www folder, and the same file is different in the asset folder too.
To be more clear that's what happen

JS file in the www folder

```
enter cordova.define('cordova/plugin_list', function(require, exports, module) {
    module.exports = [
    {
        "file": "plugins/com.ququplay.websocket.WebSocket/www/phonegap-websocket.js",
        "id": "com.ququplay.websocket.WebSocket.websocket",
        "clobbers": [
           "WebSocket"
        ]
    }
    ];
    module.exports.metadata = 
    // TOP OF METADATA
    {
        "com.ququplay.websocket.WebSocket": "0.1.0"
    }
    // BOTTOM OF METADATA
});
```

JS file in the .apk

```
cordova.define('cordova/plugin_list', function(require, exports, module) {
    module.exports = [];
    module.exports.metadata = 
    // TOP OF METADATA
    {}
    // BOTTOM OF METADATA
});
```

as you can see the file in the apk is empty, did i have to do something particular? until now i have allready install the plugin with plugman, and i had no error from tha installation, but if launch the cordova plugin ls it returns an empty list.

EDIT

I have now installed the plugin in the project's root folder plugin, if i launch cordova plugin ls it responds with the phonegap plugin, but when i build the app it still create a ccorova_plugin.js file empty.

Comment: did your app folder contains plugins folder. It seems like there is no plugins inside the plugin folder, which in turn resulted in your app. or you might have deleted the plugin, so that in www/cordovsa_plugin.js still remains erasable and app's cordova_plugin is erased

Comment: i have look into the plugins folder at the root of the project  and  it is effectively empty, but the folder in the android platform isn't empty, did i must install the plugin in the root plugin folder? i didn't do that because when i launched plugman with this module it needed the android-manifest that it is present only in the android folder.

Comment: you have install in the common www folder in order to be effective in both if you are going to use cordova build command. if you want to use only for one platform try merges. 
Hope i helped a bit.